# Getting values from an enum and assign each in a checkbox in grails

Tags: java, grails, enums

Here is my enum class

```
enum TableStatus {
AVAILABLE("Available"), OCCUPIED("Occupied"), RESERVED("Reserved"), MERGED("Merged")

static final TableStatus DEFAULT = AVAILABLE

final String value

TableStatus(String value){
    this.value = value
}

public String toString(){
    value
}
   }
```

Here is my html snippet. I cant get the syntax right on the values

```
<label class="radio-inline" style="width:auto"> <input type="radio" name="status" value="${enums.TableStatus?.AVAILABLE*}">Available</label

<label class="radio-inline" style="width:auto"> <input type="radio" name="status" value="${enums.TableStatus?.OCCUPIED*}">Occupied</label> 

<label class="radio-inline" style="width:auto"> <input type="radio" name="status" value="${enums.TableStatus?.RESERVED*}">Reserved</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input enum values as `String` such as **AVAILABLE**, **OCCUPIED**, etc...

To get back the `Enum`, convert the `String` value into an `Enum` in the controller using:

```
TableStatus statusEnum = TableStatus.valueOf("**StringValueHere**")
```

Note: to generate each radio box you can iterate on the `TableStatus` enum using a `g:each` tag:

```
<g:each var="status" in="${TableStatus.values()}">
...
</g:each>
```

Comment: I tried the codes above, i cant get it to work. Then i tried `<label class="radio-inline" style="width:auto"> <input type="radio" name="status" value="${enums.TableStatus.valueOf("AVAILABLE")}">Available</label>` in my GSP. This also doesnt work. I inspected the radio button using chrome when i ran my program. The value seems to be `Available` which is supposed to be `AVAILABLE`

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to add `.name()` after `valueOf` so it works now